# Not displaying result of two input fields values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to sum two input fields values in react. I have some issues displaying result. 
How do I save the entire calculation with the result to dropdown menu?

I think there are also asynchronous problems in my code:
the first press of the button displays only the input fields values in the dropdown menu, and only the second press of a button shows the result.

Here is my code

```
   import React from 'react'

   export default class SumCalculation extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           number1: 0,
           number2: 0,
           total: 0,
           results:[],
        }
     }
  handleChange = (e) =>{
        const {name, value} = e.target;
       this.setState({
          [name]: value
       })
   }

add = () => {
    const { number1, number2 } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        total: (parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2))
    })
    let result = { number1: this.state.number1, number2: this.state.number2, total: this.state.total};
    const t = [...this.state.results, result];
    this.setState({ results: t });
    this.setState({ number1: "" });
    this.setState({ number2: "" });
}

render() {

    let dropdown = this.state.results.map((item, id) => {
        return <option key={id}>{item.number1} + {item.number2} = {item.total}</option>
    });

    return (
        <div>

            <div>
                <label>Number 1</label>
                <input type="text" name="number1" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Number 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="number2" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.add}>Laske yhteen</button>
            <div><select>{dropdown}</select></div>
        </div>
       );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `setState()` is asynchronous, you should pass a callback function to use the updated state value. For example in your add function:

```
add = () => {

    const { number1, number2 } = this.state;

    this.setState({

        total: (parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2))

    }, () => {

        let result = { number1: this.state.number1, number2: this.state.number2, total: this.state.total};

        const t = [...this.state.results, result];

        this.setState({ results: t }, () => {

            this.setState({ number1: "" }, () => {

                this.setState({ number2: "" });

            });

        });

    })

}
```

**PS:** I added some line breaks to increase readability.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Works perfectly now :)

Comment: Happy to hear it helped :)